# Can git be configured to prevent rebase of already published commits?

Tags: git

I want to use the `git pull --rebase` instead of merge but with this approach one can accidentally rebase commits that were already pushed to another remote.
In this case the merge on pull is mandatory.

Is there a way to configure git so it rejects the rebase if some of the commits that are going to be rebased was already pushed to other remote?

Comment: Rebasing doesn't hurt your already pushed commits. It doesn't delete them from history. Why do you care?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha you're right, pushed commits stay intact, but allowing this would cause later push'es to fail unless --force is used, and at that time it's already hard to fix the things without additional rebase. Therefore if I could prevent this at rebase time, would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
git rebase --onto <remote>/<branch-name> $(git rev-list HEAD \
 --not --exclude=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD) \
 --glob=refs/* --reverse | head -1)~
```

This will rebase only commits that were done on the current local branch.

If you want to include local changes to other branches that were not pushed yet change the `--glob=refs/*` expression to `--remotes`. Please be aware, though that you may push these local branches in the future, so use with caution.

**Clarification:**
Of course, since you are not using `git pull`, you will need to execute a `git fetch` prior to rebasing. (I happen to prefer `git fetch` + `git rebase` or `git merge`, so that I can be in control of what I am rebasing onto or merging.)

Comment: I also prefer doing fetch and rebase or merge separately. However this is a large project with many developers and we need to enforce a policy, that's why it is important to specify the correct behavior for the "pull" action

Answer (score 0):

You can write hook that check to see if any commit within the range of the commits are already in the targeted branch, if so do what ever you want (like rejecting the push)

Using the git commands `git branch --contains <commit1> ... <commit_n>` you can check if the give branch contains any of the given commits.

---

#### Sumarry

git does not have anything out of the box for you, you will have to write some custom made code to do it, **but** you can use the `git branch --contains` to find out if the branch already has the given commit in it.

Comment: my concern is not that the commit is already in targeted remote branch (upstream) but in any other remote branch - in the case you mentioned the push would fail itself without the need for a specific hook, if the --force is not used, but I want to do this check at rebase time. So how to I check if the commit exists in any remote branch? do I need to go through over all existent remote branches and run --contains?